# Look for similar strings in NSArray

Tags: objective-c

Does `NSArray` have the capability of matching a string in an array with the closest representation of that string in another array?

For example:

```
NSString *search = @"apple p"; 
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"apple",@"apple pie",@"apple pies", @"apple juice", nil];

//Now we want to look for a similar string
[array ?];
```

The desired result should be: apple pie (most similar string).  Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: The same number of characters, and must have the same sequence of characters.

Comment: Should be similar to the definition above.

Comment: There are some things you can do to sort by "similarity", and then retrieve the one that sorts the highest. That would depend on implementing whatever algorithm of similar best fit your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort the array based on similarity, then retrieve the last element in the sorted array: the most similar string. Assuming you've defined some method `similarityTo:` in a category on `NSString`, something like the following should do the trick:

```
NSInteger compareStrings(id a, id b, void *context) {
  int aSimilarity = [a similarityTo:(NSString *)context];
  int bSimilarity = [b similarityTo:(NSString *)context];
  return aSimilarity - bSimilarity;
}

// Retrieving the most similar string.
NSString *result = [[array sortedArrayUsingFunction:compareStrings
                                            context:search] lastObject];
```

Comment: It looks like the closest answer i want.

Comment: @user868752: Don't forget to mark his idea as answer if it helped you.  It helps people know the question is resolved.  Just check the green mark!  ;)